# Programatically Identify All Foreign Keys that Cascade

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to use SQL to identify all foreign keys that have a cascading delete. Can someone tell me where I can find out whether a foreign key is cascading?

Thanks!

Comment: [`sys.foreign_keys`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807.aspx) or [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179987.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys 
  WHERE delete_referential_action > 0
     OR update_referential_action > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can look in informatation_schema

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
where DELETE_RULE = 'CASCADE' OR UPDATE_RULE = 'CASCADE'
```